# Streaming a http request body

Tags: c#, .net, http, streaming

I'm using an external api which allows the *request body* of a PUT request to be streamed.

I've been using a `TcpClient` to achieve this and it works fine but now we have a client that has a proxy. So I figured I'd switch to using either the `HttpClient` in .net of the `WebRequest` api.

But I haven't been able to write directly to a request body stream that actually gets sent to the server immediately.

You can get the stream of a `WebRequest` like this:

```
var req = WebRequest.Create("url");
var stream = req.GetRequestStream();
```

But this will send what you've written to the stream **after** you call `GetResponse`. And I'm not really interested in the response.

Is it possible to write directly to the server using a stream?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm very interested in doing the same.

Comment: Nope... Sorry, we ended up using the `TcpClient`